# Cascade Classifier with Multiple Positive Images

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to find the best way to create a haar classifier with opencv using a large amount of object images.

For example, on tutorial on youtube uses 1 image of a watch and uses opencv to create samples and generate about 2000 positive images.

I have about 200 variations of my positive object (for example 200 watches).

I cant really create 2000 images for each of the 200 versions of the object. Im not even sure merging the vector files would work.

Is making 200 classifiers and somehow merging them an option?

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you formulate a well defined question?

Comment: I tired. Its quite hard to explain....

Comment: Use gabor filter for data augmentation (generates X times original image) and responsive to different orientation of images.

Comment: So you have 200 image for your object? What is your scenario to make 200 classifier?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just out of ideas :P. Does it look like this watch or this watch etc

Comment: Why are you not sure that merging the vecor files would work. I have 75 positive images and that's what I do. I have a batch file that runs createsamples on each of the positive images, and then I use another tool to merge all of the .vec files. I takes under 30min total.